# Accessing a windows mail server from linux

Tags: windows, linux, samba, mail-server

I'm on a network where everyone is using Windows except me. Now I have this problem that the mail server is on a windows host `mailserv.company.local` and the only way I can access this host is through samba: `smb://mailserv.company.local` but how do I set my machine to receive mail from this server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's using standard email protocols (SMTP, IMAP/POP, etc.) then almost any email client will do. If it's an Exchange server then you'll need to use Evolution with the Exchange connector.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't clear enough. The server is using exchange that's why I struggled to connect. But looking at Evolution, I used the Echange connector as you suggested and it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

What software is the mailserver using? is it exchange?

You might be able to access it using IMAP.

See here: http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2007/03/30/howto-thunderbird-and-ms-exchange-server/

Comment: "is it exchange?" -- He said it's on a Windows host. :-)

Comment: @amphetamachine: Exchange is not the only mail server that runs on Windows.

Comment: @Ignacio: I realize that. That's what the smiley face is for.